# How to describe my "pistachios accident"?

Tags: phrase-request

I don't know how to express this minor accident of mine *precisely* and *concisely*, and also *sound natural* in English.

I was enjoying my "Dry Roasted Pistachios", given to me as a New Year present, and one of its nutshell(?) slipped into a part of my left thumb just under the nail. It slipped hard enough so part of it was shoved into my nail about  one millimeter. My thumb was bleeding a little, and it is now a little sore. Luckily, not much harm done. :-)

Then I realized that I couldn't describe what happened *precisely* and *concisely* in English, even though I could describe it very concisely in my first language (within just about 6 words). How can I describe this in English? The expression should include these followings:

- the part of that pistachio (nutshell?)
- the slipping or shoving action
- (optional) the fact that the shell went in about one millimeter deep
- the part of my thumb just under the nail (nail nook? nail cranny?)
- I was bleeding

Thank you.

Comment: PS. This is my first time with pistachios. Now I know that a good way to deal with them is to use their shells against themselves. :)

Comment: As I was cracking pistachios I accidentally stabbed myself with a shell in the quick under my thumbnail, deep enough to draw blood.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. Is there any specific word for that part under my thumbnail? (I tried looking for the word in my bilingual dictionaries but found nothing.)

Comment: The *quick*. *Quick* originally meant *alive*, as in 'the quick and the dead', and it is still used to refer to the 'living' (and acutely sensitive) flesh under the nails.

Comment: @StoneyB - I'm not sure how well-known that is; this is the first I've heard of it. I appreciate the illuminating tidbit, but I feel compelled to chime in, and mention that the O.P. might be better off sticking with "under my nail."

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Don't feel bad; even Superman has trouble with pistachios. Check out the first 40 seconds of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOvy4gOuphw).

Comment: @J.R. Really? This is a term I've known since I was a small child. Perhaps I'm showing my age. But it's there in [**OALD**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/quick_3), which doesn't go in for obscure terms.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you very much. I first time I read *stabbed myself with a shell in the quick*, I though *in the quick* was about *stabbing quickly*. I've never thought that it would be such a simple word. For J.R.: I really like that video clip. That pistachio, the one that hurt me, was really ridiculous. Bad pistachio! :-)

Comment: @Stoney - I didn't need a dictionary link; I'd taken you at your word. But now I'm curious how widely-known the term is. I'll be asking around this week.

Comment: @J.R. The link was more to reassure any learner reading these comments. I always hope our background debates will add to our visitors' understanding; but I sometimes worry it may just confuse them. ... I think I will do a Meta post on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just say:

> I was bleeding after the pistachio shell went under my nail.

I'd also be rather tempted to name the incident for future reference. I'd suggest one of the following:

> The Pistachio Incident of 2014
>   The Pistachio-tastrophe

Or, as @J.R. suggested, just shorten the last suggestion to the portmanteau:

> The Pistastrophe

Comment: :^) Or, a portmanteau: _The Pistastorphe_.

Comment: @J.R. I love it!

Comment: I love both *The Pistachio Incident of 2014* and *The Pistastorphe*. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question has long since been answered by "The Great Pistachtrophe of 2014," but I'm intrigued by the puzzle of finding a succinct way to describe it in English. This is more than six words, but:

> A pistachio shell jammed itself under my thumbnail, just deep enough to make me bleed.

1) the part of that pistachio: "A pistachio shell"

2) the slipping or shoving action: "jammed itself"

3) (optional) the fact that the shell went in about one millimeter deep, 
&  4) the part of my thumb just under the nail (nail nook? nail cranny?): 
"under my thumbnail, just deep enough"

There's no good word in common use for the specific part of your thumbnail that was injured (anatomically it's the "hyponychium," and only a few people might recognize it as the "quick"). However, the quick/hyponycium is implied by the fact that you bled, but did not need serious medical 
attention.

5) I was bleeding: "to make me bleed."

*(Now I want to study Damkerng T.'s language, at least for long enough to figure how out to say this in only six words.)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't remember exactly the six words I thought of while I was writing this question. Anyway, I think this is close enough: ถั่วทิ่มใต้เล็บเลือดซิบ ๆ (though it's 7 syllables, it's still 6 words, technically :-).

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, Thai is well beyond me. But, if you'll forgive me for subjecting your words to Google Translate, we can get the delightfully terse and vivid, if ungrammatical and vague to the point of being incorrect, five(!) words: "Beans nail prick blood dripping." Which is how we get from the pistachio-shell version of a paper cut to Hitchcock-ian drama.